# automation help within an attribute table ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, editing, arcgis-10.3, dissolve

1. I have 100+ catchments within a watershed.
2. There are 6 different types of land use classifications within in the watershed.
3. There are 5 different types of soil types within the watershed.

My example shows Catchment ID 1 is 216 acres total with 4 land use classifications and 4 types of soils. In my example I would start editing, merge the 5 highlighted, then do the same thing for the rest in catchment 1 and so on for the remaining catchments.

Question: Without individually merging same land use types with same soil types in each catchment is there a way I can automate this process.

[image: example]

Comment: I will give the dissolve function a try. Thank you both for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dissolve tool, and dissolve on the id, landuse and soils fields

Comment: This is the proper solution, but @George do note the allow multipart option in the tool dialog. It's possible, even likely, that with what you're doing those different pieces are going to be disconnected/not contiguous. Therefore combining them into a single record will (need to) create multipart features.